# summing unsigned and signed ints, same or different answer?

Tags: c

If I have the following code in C

```
int main()
{
    int x = <a number>
    int y = <a number>
    unsigned int v = x;
    unsigned int w = y;
    int ssum = x * y;
    unsigned int usum = v * w;
    printf("%d\n", ssum);
    printf("%d\n", usum);
    if(ssum == usum){
        printf("Same\n");
    } else {
        printf("Different\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Which would print the most? Would it be equal since signed and unsigned would produce the same result, then if you have a negative like -1, when it gets assigned to `int x` it becomes 0xFF, and if you want to do -1 + (-1), if you do it the signed way to get -2 = 0xFE, and since the unsigned variables would be set to 0xFF, if you add them you would still get 0xFE. And the same holds true for 2 + (-3) or -2 + 3, in the end the hexadecimal values are identical. So in C is that what's looked at when it sees signedSum == unsignedSum? It doesnt care that one is actually a large number and the other is -2, as long at the 1's and 0's are the same?

Are there any values that would make this not true?

Comment: No, C is the opposite, it looks at what values are represented and does not care about the 1's and 0's.  `-1 + -1` is always `-2`

Comment: Be aware that *signed overflow* is **undefined behaviour**. You'll often read that it wraps around, but you **must not** rely on this. *Unsigned* overflow, on the other hand, is well-defined 2's complement wrap-around.

Comment: @EOF: *Almost* correct. The wraparound of unsigned arithmetic is not related to 2's complement. (And strictly speaking it's not "overflow".)

Comment: @MattMcNabb how can -2 be assigned to an unsigned int though?

Comment: @TommyK by adjustment (mod `UINT_MAX+1`)

Answer (score 2):

The examples you have given are incorrect in C.   Also, converting between signed and unsigned types is not required to preserve bit patterns (the conversion is by value), although with some representations bit patterns are preserved.

There are circumstances where the result of operations will be the same, and circumstances where the result will differ.

- If the (actual) sum of adding two `int`s would overflow an `int`
  (i.e. value outside range that an `int` can represent) the result is
  undefined behaviour.   Anything can happen at that point (including
  the program terminating abnormally) - subsequently converting to an `unsigned` doesn't change anything.
- Converting an `int` with negative value to `unsigned int` uses modulo
  arithmetic (modulo the maximum value that an `unsigned` can
  represent, plus one).   That is well defined by the standard, but
  means -1 (type `int`) will convert to the maximum value that an
  unsigned can represent (i.e. `UINT_MAX`, an implementation defined
  value specified in `<limits.h>`).
- Similarly, adding two variables of type `unsigned int` always uses
  modulo arithmetic.

Because of things like this, your question "which would produce the most?" is meaningless.

Comment: So is this dependent on compiler or machine? I wanted to try this for myself using the real code I edited above, and when I ran this I got "same" for all the numbers, whether it was  +-1,2,3 or +-unit max. I get the same number from the print statements. Why is my result different from what you say?

Comment: The standard articulates a minimum set of requirements, and deliberately leaves some things undefined (like overflow of signed integral types), implementation-defined (such as values like UINT_MAX or INT_MAX), unspecified, etc.   That means behaviour can and does vary between compilers, machines, and even compiler settings - but will be consistent if you stick to one compiler and machine (and don't fiddle with settings that affect representation of types, if your compiler provides them).